# Replace regular expression subgroup with custom input

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to replace the captured subgroup with custom input. But, I could find suitable method in C# regular expression.
I want to replace any occurrence of characters 'O' or 'I' in between digits.
So if '123O56'(char O is present) is present it should be converted to '123056'(Char O is converted to zero).

Code is in C#

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public string ConvertCharToInt(string address)
        {
            string input = address;

            string checkPattern = @"\d+[OI]\d+";
            string patternO = @"\d+(O)\d+";
            string patternI = @"\d+(I)\d+";

            Regex regxO = new Regex(patternO, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex regxI = new Regex(patternI, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (Regex.IsMatch(input, checkPattern)){

                if (regxO.IsMatch(input))
                {
                    input = regxO.Replace(input, @"0",2);

                }
                else
                {
                    input = regxI.Replace(input, "1");
                }
            }

            return input;
        }
```

I am trying to use group number, but while providing group number, I am not able to provide custom replacement string.

Comment: Can't you do it as it is designed? `Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d+)O(\d+)", "${1}0$2")`? If you want to replace `O` with `0` and `I` with `1`, you can use a match evaluator and use a dictionary to get the right value by the matching key.

Comment: Thanks, that would solve the current issue. I would like to know if there is a way just to replace a subgroup with custom input.

Comment: No, it is not meant to be like that. You capture a group to *extract* data, to keep them, and not to remove. Although it is possible of course, but requires some effort.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You capture a group to *extract* data, to *keep* some texts, and not to remove/replace those texts.

You may match `O` or `I` in between digits and replace `O` with `0` and `I` with `1` inside a match evaluator:

```
var dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dct.Add("O", "0");
dct.Add("I", "1");
var s = "9O9 8I8";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=\d)[OI](?=\d)", m => dct[m.Value]);
Console.WriteLine(result); // => 909 818
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/rbRnql).

Here, `(?<=\d)[OI](?=\d)` pattern matches either `O` or `I` in between digits and the value (`m.Value`) is used as a key to find the corresponding value in the dictionary.

With capturing groups:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d)([OI])(\d)", 
            m => $"{m.Groups[1].Value}{dct[m.Groups[2].Value]}{m.Groups[3].Value}");
```

See [another C# demo](https://ideone.com/WZfATh).